# How to create new folder in web-app from bootstrap in Grails?

Tags: grails

I am trying to create new folder in folder web-app and I would like to create on run-app. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have already said it it should be created on run-app then should be placed inside `bootstrap.groovy` file.

[Using groovy I/O operation](http://grsage.com/groovy/GroovyIO.html)

`Boolean  exists ( ) -returns true if the file or directory exists
Boolean  mkdir ( ) - creates a directory if it doesn't exist.
String      getPath ( )   - returns String with the full pathname.`

Using the above :

```
def createDir(dirName) {

String final static dirpath = '/web-app/'+dirname

  File pathDir = new File(dirpath).mkdirs()

       if (pathDir.exists()){
          println("Directory$dirpath created");
       }else{
          println(" Failed to create Directory$dirpath / directory already exists !");
       }
}
```

ALLOHA!